# How to insert a UITableView inside a UITableViewCell and make the UITableView not scrollable?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image][image][image]

The above pictures are from the Blue Apron app. This specific page has a scrollable view (let's just say `UITableView` ) and within that `UITableView` they have this one section called `Instructions` which has cells numbered (1,2,3, etc.) as seen in the pictures above.

I assuming inside of that `Instructions` Section they have a `UITableView` to display those cells (`Cook the freekeh`, `Prepare the ingredients`, etc). But how do they make that `UITableView` unscrollable and make it scroll with the main `UITableView`?

I basically want to know how they get those list of views in that instruction section within that main `UITableView` without having it scroll.

Does anyone have any ideas or am I interpreting this completely wrong and there is a better method?

Comment: its perfectly posible, you must calculate the final height of your insides tableViews, and mark them as not scrolleable, this is more easy to achieve when your inside tableviewCells have an static height but is posible with dynamic height also

Comment: @ReinierMelian So if it was static height I could do something like this: `tableview.frame = CGRectMake(SOME_X, SOME_Y, tableview.frame.size.width, tableview.frame.size.height+(resultArray.count*HEIGHT_OF_CELL));` But where would I put this code? Like after I grab my model objects from the network? So essentially right before I called `tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: You have to make a custom cell with UItableView inside and implement all those methods from DataSource and Delegate, your cell will be the tableview, the you need to pass to your cell an array of objects and if your cells will have a fixed height your external cell height will be numberOfCells  * heigth I think I can post an example on github for you if you want, its hard to explain, and Iam not english native speaker

Comment: @ReinierMelian Oh ok I get what you are saying. If you have time, an example would be cool but not required. Thanks for the input!

Comment: OK, anyway @vikram seems to have an example, hope that helps, best regards

Comment: @ReinierMelian @ReinierMelian I have a quick clarification. So I used Vikram's starter project and modified it to have two sections each with one row. In the second section I return a cell with a `UITableView` inside of that `UITableViewCell`. The problem is that although I set the content size of the `UITableView` inside of that `UITableViewCell` to `numberOfCells * height`, the `UITableViewCell` cell also has to be the same height as the `UITableView` that is contained inside of it. Do you know how I would do that? Let me post what I did one second.

Comment: ok, post and i tell you

Comment: HEre it is: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q8p8e5c83z4afs7/AABr60ZOcxFNeyZOvJubhFZra?dl=0 Can you please take a look at the heightForRowAtIndexPath in the ViewController.swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150542/discussion-between-1290-and-reinier-melian).

Comment: @CapturedTree Did your issue resolved. I am facing some kind of same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this you tube tutorial created by me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQ1DfCI93pU

Just you need to replace collectionview with tableview.

Hope it will help!.

Comment: Hi vikram. Thanks for the video but I am already aware how to do something like that. I need to create a view similar to the one I posted on my question.

Comment: I have created a sample for you. you can download from this link https://github.com/vikramsinghrajpoot/TableViewSections

Comment: That is great thank you so much. But I was looking to create it in a different way. Have two sections. And in the second section have a UITableViewCell with a UITableView inside of it.

Comment: HEre it is: dropbox.com/sh/q8p8e5c83z4afs7/AABr60ZOcxFNeyZOvJubhFZra?dl=‌​0 Can you please take a look at the heightForRowAtIndexPath in the ViewController.swift

Comment: @vikram Can you check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63393358/how-can-i-access-height-of-inside-tableviewcell-in-the-maintableviewcell-in-swif