# How can I access Height of inside tableviewcell in the maintableviewcell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new in Swift and I am unable to access the height of inside UITableviewCell in main UITableviewCell.

In my main tableviewcell my code in cellforrowatindexpath my code is like this:

```
cell.constraintHeightOfTblView.constant = CGFloat(135 * (cell.arrCourses.count))
```

I created the height constraint of inside tableview and I am multiplying it based on the count of array. It works. But if the data in cell increase it is not getting the height proper because I define here static height.

So I want the inside tableviewcell height so it could work proper. Can I access it?

I want to achieve this:

[image]

But I am getting this as the content of insidetableviewcell is increased

[image]

Inside tableviewcell is scrolling I do not want the inside tableview cell to scroll differently.

Comment: Can some one please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: do you need multiple cells like this with growing text?

Comment: @vikram No In my case it is tableview inside tableview.

Comment: so test1 and test2 inside another tableview?

Comment: @vikram Upper profile view, comment ,accept and reject button are in main tableview and start time,end time, test are in insidetableview

Comment: @Muju try set height for cell in height for row after calculating or put fixed height or subtable in cell try to manipulate height constraints based on calculation, then will work

Comment: @kamaleshkumaryadav How can I do it can you please share some code for it

Comment: There are two workaround for that:
1> Use multiple sections with dynamic cell height.
2> If table view inside table view than calculate the height of inner tablecell with some calculation like (text height + timeview height) at run time.

Comment: @vikram Second one I am doing but how can I get text height from inner tableviewcell?

Comment: you can use something like this:

extension String {
    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font], context: nil)
        return boundingBox.height
    }
}

Comment: @vikram how to use this extension and how to get height with it?

Comment: calculate the height at heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate
By simply calling this on any string or text.

Comment: @Muju you have UITableView inside a UITableViewCell, right?

Answer (score 3):

**Purpose** of this code is to provide a tableView a height that fits its content size and stop scrolling.

Previously that was achieved using height constraint on tableView.

Steps if your tableView is inside Storyboard or xib:

1. Create a swift file named SelfSizedTableView.
2. **Provide** SelfSizedTableView to your tableView that is inside Storyboard or xib.
3. No need to provide height constraint to tableView.
4. Just go to **Size Inspector** go to bottom and set **Intrinsic
   Size** to placeholder, without checking boxes of height and width.

If your tableView is created programmatically, make sure its a child of SelfSizedTableView.

```
import UIKit

class SelfSizedTableView: UITableView {

/*
// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

func defaultSetup() {
    // do something here
}

override open func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    defaultSetup()
}

override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
    super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    defaultSetup()
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    defaultSetup()
}

/// set a value to maxHeight if you want tableView to scroll after a specific height
/// e.g. when contentSize.height > maxHeight
/// table view will start to scroll

var maxHeight: CGFloat?

/// set a value to minHeight if you want tableView to avoid scroll before specific height
/// e.g. when contentSize.height > minHeight
/// table view will start to scroll

var minHeight: CGFloat?

override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()
    self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let height: CGFloat
    
    if let maxHeight = maxHeight {
        height = min(contentSize.height, maxHeight)
    }
    else if let minHeight = minHeight {
        height = max(contentSize.height, minHeight)
    }
    else {
        height = contentSize.height
    }
    
    return CGSize(width: contentSize.width, height: height)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can try using below delegate method to provide the height for each row in your tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   // calculate the height and return.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

}
```

Also try un-ckecking Automatic check box for "Row Height" and "Estimate" in the Size Inspector of Tableview as below:
[image]

You can take IBOutlet of inside Tableview and get height from bounds like insideTableView.bounds.height

If you need the cell height of the main tableview then you can try to get like mainTableView.rowHeight or mainTableView.estimatedRowHeight

If you don't want the inside Table view scroll then you can disable scrolling by unchecking Scrolling Enabled in Attribute Inspector

Comment: I have tableview inside tableview

Comment: Then you can take IBOutlet of inside Tableview and get height from bounds like insideTableView.bounds.height

Comment: I want cell height tableview height is not working properly

Comment: You mean you need the cell height of the main tableview then you can try to get like mainTableView.rowHeight or mainTableView.estimatedRowHeight